# aes parameter to anchor start and end points for ggplot geom_smooth regression (loess)?

Tags: r, ggplot2, regression, loess

Is there a parameter that can anchor start and end points for a loess geom_smooth regression? If I increase the span (so that the regression isn't too wiggly), the starting and ending points seem to be drastically different (I have multiple lines on a graph, using as.factor) when in reality they are not (quite close together). I can't share my data as it is for confidential academic research, and I'm not sure how to reproduce an example for this... just wondering if this is possible with ggplot.

Here are some pictures that illustrate the problem, though...

Low span (span = 0.1), just the first 10 out of the 750 points to be graphed --> with this you can see the true starting points:

[image]

And then with the high span (span = 1.0), and all 750 points, the starting value and ending values are completely different. I'm not sure why this happens, but it is very misleading:

[image]

Basically, I want the smoothness of the second picture, but the specific and accurate starting points of the first when I graph all of the data (i.e., all 750 points). Let me know if there's any way to do this. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your code, I can already tell that you're setting your axis limits for the "span = 1.0" version using `xlim(0,10)` or `scale_x_continuous(limits=c(0,10))` - is that correct?  Change it to the following:

```
coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0, 10))
```

This is because `xlim()` (which is just a wrapper for `scale_x_continuous(limits=...)`) does not just zoom in on your data, but in fact *discards* any of the data outside of those limits before performing any calculations.  Check [the documentation](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/lims.html) on `xlim()` and [the documentation](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/coord_cartesian.html) on `coord_cartesian()` for more info.

It's easy to see how this is working using the following example:

```
# create dataset
set.seed(8675309)
df <- data.frame(x=1:1000, y=rnorm(1000))

# basic plot
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + theme_bw() +
    geom_point(color='gray75', size=1) + geom_smooth()
p
```

We get a basic plot, and as we expect, the result of `geom_smooth()` on this dataset is a straight line parallel to the x axis at y=0.

[image]

If we use `xlim()` or `scale_x_continuous(limits=...)` to see the first 10 points, you see that the `geom_smooth()` line is not the same:

```
p + xlim(0,10)

# or this one... results in the same plot
p + scale_x_continuous(limits=c(0,10))
```

[image]

The resulting line has a much higher standard deviation and is a bit above y=0, since the first 10 points happen to be just a bit above the average for the rest of the 990 points.  If you use `coord_cartesian(xlim=...)`, the zooming in of the plot happens *after* the calculations are made and no points are discarded, giving you the same points plotted, but the `geom_smooth()` line that matches that of the full dataset:

```
p + coord_cartesian(xlim=c(0,10))
```

[image]